# Nuxt 2: in preview mode, vuex getters do not work

Tags: javascript, nuxt.js, vuex

When in preview mode (@see https://nuxtjs.org/docs/features/live-preview) Vuex getters do not appear to work, at least with data that's fetched.

Accessing the data from the store directly works.

Accessing the data via a getter which then calls the same code from the store, returns undefined.

Data is fetched (technically, using axios) via `nuxtServerInit`, but the issue is the same if I change that to fetch (using axios) via `asyncData` from within my template.

These are two simple examples (using actual code that exhibits this issue)

This only happens when preview mode is enabled and using `target: static`

```
enablePreview()
```

Why? Why don't getters work? It's like the state that the getters are accessing is different to the state that I access when I access it directly.

### Example 1:

/store/index.js

```js
export const getters = {
    getURLData(state) {
        return state?.urls ?? [];
    },
    getPageData: (state, getters) => (url) => {
        const a = state?.urls; // [array,of,urls]
        const b = getters.getURLData; // undefined
        
        ...
    }
```

### Example 2:

store/index.js

```js
export const getters = {
    getSettings(state) {
        return state?.settings;
    }
}
```

whatever.vue

```
export default {
    head() {
        const a = this.$store.getters.getSettings; // undefined
        const b = this.$store.state?.settings; // {data}
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I think that the problem is in your way of calling vuex getters, try to use MapGetters instead of accessing it directly via this.$store.

```js
import { mapGetters } from 'vuex'
export default {
.....
     computed: {
        ...mapGetters({
          settings: 'getSettings',
        }),
     }
....
}
```

Comment: How do you use mapGetters in /store/index.js? See example 1 where the problem exists within the store.